# Loading gulp tasks in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, gulp, webstorm

I have some strange problem. I have project with `gulpfile.babel.js`. Everything worked fine. But some days ago WebStorm stopped loading gulp tasks.

I use `Node 4.4.4`. I use **local gulp package**. If I run gulp tasks manually using gulp configurations it works, but shows no output in console. I speak about such ouput

```
[14:56:14] Starting 'serve:ide'...
[14:56:14] Starting 'clean:tmp'...
[14:56:14] Starting 'clean:tmpsrv'...
[14:56:14] Starting 'constant'...
[14:56:14] Starting 'env:all'...
[14:56:14] Finished 'env:all' after 6.46 ms
[14:56:14] Starting 'typings'...
etc...
```

In console gulp works fine. What can cause such issue?

I use gulp file generate by this template https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack .

I use the template with TypeScript on client, Jade, mocha and gulp options.

Comment: No idea. what error do you see when trying to load gulp tasks?

Comment: No errors.  Simply writes,  that there is no tasks.  I have recreated project and reinstalled gul-cli,  and now everything works fine.

Comment: Same problem after webstorm update. I use gulp to transpile es6+ to es5 then start a project from build/index.js. So, my start config: before project starting start gulp task then starts an app. For some reason, it start only gulp task then stop and that's all. No errors, warning... reinstalling, recreating project didn't help